# Get maximum of a speed (number) in Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am working on app to watch how fast you run, **and for that I need a function that shows what your maximum speed has been.** but can not find how I do.

```
local speedText = string.format( '%.3f', event.speed )
speed.y = 250
speed.x = 125
local numValue = tonumber(speedText)*3.6
if numValue ~= nil then
    speed.text = math.round( numValue )
end
```

I've made my "speedText" to a number that you see above.

I code in Corona SDK/**Lua**

Answer (score 0):

You need to track the speed in every frame, and do something simple like that:

```
if event.speed > currentMaxSpeed then
    currentMaxSpeed = event.speed;
end
```